# Limit using L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: limits

So my question is how to find
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\left(\pi-2\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) \right)$$

the answer should be 2

Comment: good! What have you done? Where are you stuck? :)

Comment: I really can not understand what to do the next step.

Comment: Write $1/x$ as denominator.

Comment: Hint: You have the indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$, you want either $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$. @AaronMaroja gives a good complementary hint

Comment: The differentiation is more pleasant if the arcsine is written as $\arctan x$.

Comment: So what to do after he brought in the denominator of x?

Comment: Use L'Hospital!

Comment: ok, now try....

Comment: We are looking at $\frac{\pi-2\arctan x}{1/x}$. Differentiate top and bottom and simplify. We get $\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}$. Now it's over.

Comment: @ André Nicolas wait.. and where the root of the missing?

Comment: I used the fact that $\arcsin(x/\sqrt{x^2+1})=\arctan x$. That got rid of the square root stuff.

Comment: I think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(x)=\left(x\left(\pi-2\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) \right)$$
Putting $\frac{1}{x}$ to the denominator, we have 
$$F(x)=\frac{\left(\pi-2\arcsin\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$
The derivative of the numerator is $\frac{-2}{1+x^2}$ when $x\gt 0$ and the derivative of the denominator is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ and therefore the limit is $2$

Answer (score 1):

As $\arcsin y+\arccos y=\dfrac\pi2$

We have
$$F=2\lim_{x\to\infty^+}x\arccos\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

W/O L'Hôpital's rule,

Set $x=\cot y\implies x^2+1=\csc^2y$  $$F=2\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac y{\sin y}\cdot\cos y$$

Using L'Hôpital's rule, set $1/x=y$

$$F/2=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\arccos\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+y^2}}}y$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{-\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-1/(1+y^2)}}\cdot-\dfrac{2y}{2(1+y^2)^{3/2}}}1$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{y}{y(1+y^2)^{3/2-1/2}}$$

as $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$ which is $+y$ here as $y>0$

Comment: Thanks, but what will be the final answer?

Comment: @Andre, Hope the last line should be too tough to evaluate

Comment: So the answer must be 2 !!!

Comment: @Andre, $$\frac1{(1+0^2)}=?$$

Comment: exactly ... thanks :)